# Why use decorators, Where it will prove advantages

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am going through the angularjs from a couple of weeks, have reached the decorators, what i have understood is that, it will just decorate/modify the existing directive by addning or modifing the existing objects of directive,

My question is Why not we directly do the same in the directive itself in the first place, why  we need to write a abstract directive, and then do config() the directive at later stage,

Any advantage of using this kind of Behavior?, When it will prove, it is worth Using the decorators.

NOTE: Since i am a learner, it may be a simple or silly point, but please do advice,

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can decorate directives. Decorators are used to override or modify services. It is typically used to modify/enhance/replace/wrap 3rd party or upstream services that you don't own. The advantages are many, I'll list some that I can think of off the top of my head:

1. You can modify, enhance or replace 3rd party of build-in services
   that would not make sense to modify at the source. This answer gives
   a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16078515/202913
2. You can completely replace a service. As an example you can replace
   the build-in $log service with your own implementation that logs to
   your server or store logs in local storage.
3. You can wrap services for logging/tracing purposes.
4. You can wrap services to inject data before calling the actual
   service methods, e.g. injecting a security token before call $http
   methods.

It is a powerful feature and opens many doors.

Comment: Actually you can decorate directives: http://briantford.com/blog/angular-hacking-core