# Extend existing service in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular growl service ([angular-growl](https://github.com/marcorinck/angular-growl)), and i need one method to add growl with specific type, e.g.

```
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', 'growl', function ($scope, growl) {
     growl.add("Message", "INFO");
}
```

is it possible to append new method to growl service (or append method to any service) when angular start process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can use the concept of Angular `decorator` to extend the existing service. This is done through `$provide.decorator`. An implementation would look something like this:

```
app.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('growl', function($delegate) {
    $delegate.add = function(message, type) {
      // implementation for add.
    };
    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

Read more about it in this SO post [What are "decorators" and how are they used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075982/angularjs-what-are-decorators-and-how-are-they-used)