# AngularJS: decorator is the best way to extend the existing service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have seen this answer of question **[Extend existing service in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28317781/3331328)** where concept of decorator in angularjs is doing right things for the same

```
app.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('growl', function($delegate) {
    $delegate.add = function(message, type) {
      // implementation for add.
    };
    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

but my question is

**Is decorator in AngularJS the best way to extend the existing service?**

Or there are some other functionality related to extend existing service in AngularJS?

Comment: There are other ways: mixings, extend underlaying class, delegation and composition of service (not quite extension, but achieves same goals).

Comment: Depending on your scenario you perhaps can find a different approach (as pointed on the previous comment) but, speaking about angularjs, it's very much attached to its architecture so it's a little hard to escape from what angularjs gives you. Therefore, I believe decorator is the way to go.

Comment: Here is an alternative to `decorator` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293943/how-can-i-extend-a-service