# Decorating a service provider in Angular

Tags: angularjs, decorator

I'm working on a library that extends some of the functionality in `ui.router` for building out sets of application states. Currently I am managing this by defining a new provider in my library (let's call it `enhancedState`) in the form:

```
myApp.provider('enhancedState', EnhancedState);

EnhancedState.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];
function EnhancedState ($stateProvider) {
  this.$stateProvider = $stateProvider;
}
EnhancedState.prototype = {
  /* fun new methods that wrap $stateProvider */
  $get: ['$state', function ($state) {
    /* maybe wrap some $state functionality too */
    return $state;
  }
};
```

I can then use my `enhancedStateProvider` in my application config to do fun new state definitions following the extended capabilities of my library.

I would prefer, however, to directly decorate the `$stateProvider` class. I am aware of Angular's `$provider.decorate()` utility, but as far as I can tell, it can only be used to decorate the generated service instances, not the provider.

Has anyone successfully used it to decorate providers, or is aware of a similar mechanism to do so in Angular 1.x?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You need [AngularJS decorators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide) (find `decorator` method). Check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/lj9srM2KXZmwmTxLb1p7?p=preview) plunker example. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075982/what-are-decorators-and-how-are-they-used) so post.

Example:

```
app.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('$state', function($delegate) {
    $delegate.customMethod = function(a) {
      console.log(a);
    };
    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

Comment: Correct, just it should be `$provide.decorator('$state', ...`

Comment: Woops. Updated. I don't know anything about `$state` provider and don't know that I should inject something created as provider with `Provider` postfix. Main point was using `$provide.decorator` :)

Comment: Hey, that's actually the very first thing I tried, but in my case I don't want to decorate `$state`, I want to decorate `$stateProvider`, which is the object that creates `$state`. This is what I can't find a way to reconcile with `$provide.decorator`

Comment: Anything on this issue?

Comment: How would you decorate `$stateProvider` (as the OP asked)?