# How to override or add some functionality to the existing AngularJS services?

Tags: angularjs

I want to override or add some more functionality to existing services like $http, $log and so on 
how to do that?

Comment: The source code is here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src fork it and add your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the $provide.decorator method for extending any angular services, the definition of a decorator as per the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator):

> A service decorator intercepts the creation of a service, allowing it to override or modify the behavior of the service. The object returned by the decorator may be the original service, or a new service object which replaces or wraps and delegates to the original service.

Came across this [link](http://blog.xebia.com/extending-angularjs-services-with-the-decorate-method/) by Freek Wielstra which might help you in taking this further.

**Edit:** 
Please check this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075982/what-are-decorators-and-how-are-they-used) by @tomakisquare, he has provided a brilliant plunkr example to extend third party services (or any service for that matter) without meddling with the original code.

Comment: Thanks for the your answer !!