# AngularJS - Manipulate elements from an extension's directive without touching the core files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetimepicker, dom-manipulation

Here's the scenario... I'm using [**AngularJS**](https://angularjs.org/) and I need to do some **modifications to the [Datetimepicker](https://github.com/zhaber/angular-js-bootstrap-datetimepicker) extension** without **modifying the core files or use other extensions**.

Anyway, all I needed to do was to **clear the *timepicker*** by means of a function (maybe?). The original [**Timepicker**](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#timepicker) this extension is based upon seems to allow clearance of the time.

Here's my first attempt: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1V90gk?p=preview)

Here's the function:

```
  $scope.clearPicker = function() {
    $scope.date = null;
    $scope.date.setHours(0); // Trying to clear the Timepicker
  };
```

Another attempt is to resort to jQuery: [plunkr2](http://plnkr.co/edit/1akqkG?p=preview)

Here's the function:

```
  $scope.clearPicker = function() {
    $scope.date = null;

    angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('datetimepicker-wrapper'))
    .find('input')
    .val('');
  };
```

But of course many would say that the latter is **not the Angular way**.

So how should I go about **injecting functions into an extension**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are "decorators" and how are they used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075982/what-are-decorators-and-how-are-they-used)

Comment: looking at the code of that directive, the authors *intentionally* designed it to never allow the time to be reset once set, and even have commented in the code in a few places as to why.  If you don't intend to modify this directive, then your only alternative would be to contact the authors for an alternative, or post a bug in their bug tracker.

Comment: @Claies It's times like this that made me prefer jQuery. So there is no way I can manipulate another's directive at all?

Comment: @MartijnWelker: I took a look at your suggestion and I honestly don't know where to start. I'm new to Angular. Any hints?

Comment: of course you can manipulate the directive, but you specifically stated that you didn't want to modify it.

Comment: @Giraldi A decorator is used to modify 3rd party services/factories/directives without having to change the code in the source, you can read more about it here: http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/09/experiment-decorating-directives/ (It's an example about directives but it works the save for services)

Comment: @Claies: That's exactly what I meant. If given a situation where modifying the core files is not an option, what solution does Angular provides?

Comment: as @MartijnWelker has mentioned, you can use decorators to modify the behavior of 3rd party directives.  However, you seem to be insinuating that the Angular Developers are somehow at fault for the 3rd party directive not working the way you expected it to?  Otherwise, why would it be Angular's responsibility to provide a solution?

Comment: Really I'm not trying to blame Angular Devs in any way. I'm just trying to find out how to do this the **Angular way**. I'm just so used to the ease of use of jQuery. I'm still trying to study this **"decorators"** and trying to figure out how to implement it for my situation.